# Issues iterating dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am filling out a dataframe using the content of a list of lists such as:

```
desc_prep=[['aesthet', 'abod'], [['arb', 'abod'], ['forest', 'abod']]]

col_names =  ['desc_name','desc_avg_vector']
df_desc_prep = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)    
df_desc_prep['desc_name']=desc_prep
```

At this point of time I am getting the following:

```
                         desc_name
0                [aesthet, abod]
1  [[arb, abod], [forest, abod]]
```

When iterating the dataframe with iteritems to get a tuple with the column name and the content as a Series:

```
for index, value in df_desc_prep.iteritems():
    print("index: ", index)#-->index:  desc_name
    print("value: ", value)#-->value:  0                  [aesthet, abod]
    print("value[0]:", value[0])#['aesthet', 'abod']
    print("value[1]:", value[1])#[['arb', 'abod'], ['forest', 'abod']]
    if isinstance(value[0], list):#->value[0]:  ['aesthet', 'abod']
```

When iterating using iterrows() to get a Series for each row:

```
for index, value in df_desc_prep.iterrows():
    print("index: ", index)#-->index:  0
    print("value: ", value)#-->value:  desc_name    [aesthet, abod]
    if isinstance(value[0], list):#-->value[0]:  ['aesthet', 'abod'], value[1]: IndexError: index out of bounds
```

I was expecting to get value[0] as `aesthet` and value[1] as `abod`. Instead I am getting `IndexError: index out of bounds` when getting value[1].

How can I get the behaviour of iterating over the dataframe and getting `value[0]=aesthet` when iterating over `['aesthet', 'abod']` and `value[0]=['arb', 'abod']` when iterating over `[['arb', 'abod'], ['forest', 'abod']]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
for index, value in df_desc_prep.iterrows():
    print(value[0][0])
    print(value[0][1])

aesthet
abod
['arb', 'abod']
['forest', 'abod']
```

---

```
for index, value in df_desc_prep.iterrows():
    print(value['desc_name'][0])
    print(value['desc_name'][1])

aesthet
abod
['arb', 'abod']
['forest', 'abod']
```

Comment: Well done!!! Works as a charm. A question, why you have to indicate the name of the column even when is a dataframe of one column (a series)? For instance,  `col_names =  ['desc_name']   df_desc_prep =pd.DataFrame(columns=col_names)`

Comment: @JuanPerez so that you can see that we can access elements with column_name also in case there are more columns.